# How can i sync graphooper or maps.me map data (mwm or .map file and offline routing data) with server and device

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I want to edit map data from server , for example i want to close a street from server and offline routing will update and users dont route from closed street, after a time street will be open from server. how can i do this?

Comment: please show me a solution i follow,

Comment: I don't think there is a ready-made solution for you available. Where are you stuck exactly? Downloading a file from a server to your device is not rocket science.